# Keras ValueError: Shapes (32, 2) and (32, 4) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I just posted about another problem with the same code, but progress is extremely slow due to the fact that I know very little about what I'm doing. The link to the previous problem is here:
[Keras ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641596/keras-valueerror-no-gradients-provided-for-any-variable/62641891?noredirect=1#comment110777992_62641891)

I'm currently trying to get my model to run in order to classify 5000 different events which are 2D numpy arrays of 29x29 values

I define my NN like so:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(29,29,1))

x=inputs

x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), name='Conv_1')(x)
x = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)      
x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2), name='MaxPool_1')(x)

x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), name='Conv_2')(x)
x = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2), name='MaxPool_2')(x)

x = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), name='Conv_3')(x)
x = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2), name='MaxPool_3')(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten(name='Flatten')(x)

x = keras.layers.Dense(64, name='Dense_1')(x)
x = keras.layers.ReLU(name='ReLU_dense_1')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, name='Dense_2')(x)
x = keras.layers.ReLU(name='ReLU_dense_2')(x)

outputs = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='Output')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='VGGlike_CNN')
model.summary()

keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

OPTIMIZER = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR_ST)

model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              run_eagerly=False)

def lr_decay(epoch):
  if epoch < 10:
    return LR_ST
  else:
    return LR_ST * tf.math.exp(0.2 * (10 - epoch))

lr_scheduler = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_decay)


model_checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath='mycnn_best',
        monitor='val_accuracy',
        save_weights_only=True, 
        save_best_only=True,
        save_freq='epoch')

callbacks = [ lr_scheduler, model_checkpoint ]    

print('X_train.shape = ',X_train.shape)

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train epochs=50,
                    validation_data=X_test, shuffle=True, verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

It now gives me the error: ValueError: Shapes (32, 2) and (32, 4) are incompatible.

I want to classify each of the events has having 1,2,3 or 4 clusters, but before working on something complex, I'm using events which I know only have 1 cluster, so the label for each event is 1.

All of this gives me the idea that the problem is to do with my output being 4 neurons, but I really don't know if that's true, nor do I know how to go about debugging the code.

If anyone could help me I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Could you provide the shape of your labels?

Comment: labels is a numpy array with shape (5000, 2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue comes from the difference between the shape of your labels and the output shape of your model. Since you are using `categorical_crossentropy` and there are 4 units for your output layer, your model expects labels in one hot encoded form and as a vector of length 4. However, your labels are vectors of length 2. Therefore, if your labels are integers, you can do

```
Y_train = tf.one_hot(Y_train, 4)
```

and the resulting shape will be `(5000, 4)`.

Comment: Now when I do: X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(NormEvents,labels,train_size=train_to_test_ratio)
I get the error:
Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array([2124, 4508, 2518, ..., 4349, 2902, 2374])
Please can you help me fix this?

Comment: Since you can't index tensors with arrays, you will need to split your data before your encoding step. Once you have your train and test labels, you can encode them separately.

Comment: That's great, it's solved those two problems - however now when I try to train the model, after the end of the first epoch I get the error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". Is the problem that the shape of the labels is now Y_train.shape =  (4000, 4)? If it is, please can you help me solve this too? (If necessary I'll open a new question, I just thought this would be efficient)

Comment: Since the issue occurs at the end of the epoch, your training data is fine, but there is an issue with your test data. From the code you posted, it seems that you are only using `X_test`. Validation data requires both the inputs and labels, so you must also provide `y_test`.

Comment: It's running! Thank you so much for all of your help

Comment: This answer has helped me a lot, 3 years later! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your model.summary() clearly shows what your model expects at each step. In particular, your model expects data that looks like (batch_size,29,29,1) and outputs data that looks like (batch_size,4). If your label data is not of the form (batch_size,4) then that will create an error if those are to be compared by the loss function.

It is unclear how you are labeling your data. You say some data is labeled as a "1". Not sure what that means. Data can be label in one of two ways:

```
A -> 0
B -> 1
C -> 2
D -> 1
```

or

```
A -> (1,0,0)
B -> (0,1,0)
C -> (0,0,1)
D -> (0,1,0)
```

The second set is known as "one hot encoding" your labels. Keras will automatically one hot encode your labels if you use the "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" loss function, and your labels are integers (starting at 0). If you manually one hot encode your data yourself, then you would use the "categorical_crossentropy" loss function instead (it sounds like you may have done this).

The difference between these labeling methods comes from the fact that labels as integers unavoidably place your labels on a continuum. For example, the label of "2" is closer to a label of "1" than a label of "0". Hence, the algorithm will natural not think a label of "2" (for a "1") is as bad of a guess as a label of "2" (for a "0"). By "one hot encoding" all the data, we have made all the labels an equal distance apart from each other, so there is no favoritism in the labels.

I always recommend testing your model on random data to make sure everything is working. For example,

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

X = np.random.random((10000,29,29,1))
Y = np.random.randint(0,4,size=10000)
Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y)

print(f"Input: {X.shape}, Output: {Y.shape}")

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(64,'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64,'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(4,'softmax'),
])

model.compile('adam','categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X,Y)
```

Comment: Really clear, thank you. What I meant was that in the data file with the labels, each of the labels is 1 (A->1, B->1 etc.). I used one-hot encoding for exactly these reasons, and as Richard X said, I needed to ensure that when I did the one-hot encoding, the resulting object had size of 4, as my output expected. Having changed that, I now get the error that I describe above in reply to his answer. I would be extremely grateful if you could help me fix this bug too!